# Programatically saving an image to a Django ImageField is creating an infinite loop of images

Tags: python, django

I've got a `save` method on a model that looks like so:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    img_url = "http://example.com/%s.jpg" % (self.title)
    name = urlparse(img_url).path.split('/')[-1]
    content = urllib.urlretrieve(img_url)
    self.image.save(name, File(open(content[0])), save=True)
    super(Test, self).save(force_insert, force_update)
```

For some reason, this is creating an infinite loop of image creations with ever more `_`s in the filename. I finally figured out it was doing that when I got a Django error that said that the file it was trying to save had too many characters (I found 242 images saved).

I was trying to use information from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url).

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think from a browse through the source code that calling `ImageFileField.save()` (actually `FileField.save()` due to inheritance) causes the instance (namely the db row) that the file name is stored in to be updated.

This means that in your `save` method you call `ImageFileField.save()` which in turn calls your save method, causing the recursion.

From reading the source code, if you want to prevent this, then just pass `save=False` to `self.image.save`.  This will save the file data to disk, but just won't `save` the instance (db row) data.  However in the next line you save it by calling the superclass, so I think it will be saved to the database then.

In fact it looks like that the `save=False` on the `save` method was designed to help with this case!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain, but it could be that when `self.image.save` is called, it calls the save method of the model, by default, as well - Thus creating your infinite loop. I haven't tested it but I could see that happening.

My suggestion if that is the issue: Send a [signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#topics-signals) from within the models save method containing that instance and then have a seperate function to download/parse the image and save it.