# Django proxy download?

Tags: django

I have seen on a few websites an option to download files from remote url, as though that website is used as a proxy.You would put url into input box and downlod would start but through that website, so I was wondering how is that possible to achieve with django?

Comment: The next can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3445568/python-django-download-image-from-url-modify-and-save-to-imagefield

Comment: Seems like this is what I've been looking for http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-http-proxy/0.3