# django: Save image from url inside another model

Tags: python, django

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'read', blank=True)
    creative_url = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    description = RichTextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        content = urllib2.urlopen(self.creative_url).read()
        self.image.save("test.jpg", File(content))
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Gives exception:
'str' object has no attribute 'name'

I was trying to follow this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url) But it did not help to get rid of the exception.

---

```
AttributeError at /admin/collection/item/1/ 'str' object has no attribute 'name' Request Method:    POST Request
URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/collection/item/1/ Django
Version:    1.2.5 Exception Type:   AttributeError Exception Value:  'str'
object has no attribute 'name' Exception
Location:   D:\FF\django\core\files\base.py in _get_size, line 39 Python
Executable: C:\Python27\python.exe Python Version:  2.7.2 Python
Path:   ['D:\\FF',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_social_auth-0.6.7-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\python_openid-2.2.5-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\oauth2-1.5.211-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\httplib2-0.7.4-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\selenium-2.20.0-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\ipython-0.12-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\django_localeurl-1.5-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pil-1.1.7-py2.7-win32.egg',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\pip-1.1-py2.7.egg',
'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs',
'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27',
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages',
'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages'] Server time:    Tue, 24 Apr 2012
14:19:00 +0300
```

Comment: Show the real exception and traceback, please.

Comment: Have you posted your entire model? It sounds like this isn't related directly to the image saving. Is there a unicode method on your model?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `File`, you need to use [`django.core.files.base.ContentFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class)

```
self.image.save("test.jpg", ContentFile(content), save=False)
```

`File` accepts file object or `StringIO` object having `size` property or you need to manually set `size` property of a `File` or `ImageFile` to make it working w/ `StringIO`:

```
s = StringIO()
s.write(urllib2.urlopen(self.creative_url).read())
s.size = s.tell()
self.image.save('test.jpg', File(s), save=False)
```

Also, please note the `save=False` inside `self.image.save`: by default, `save=True`, this will cause the instance, which contains the image field, to be saved. Thus the `save` logic in your code might encounter an infinite loop and reach maximum recursion depth.

Comment: Love your answer because I was in that inf loop :)

Comment: Great answer! Although I had to remove `save=False` since it caused the image to not save into the model field, but without it it works fine (perhaps because I used a model method and didn't override in `.save()`?)

Comment: @Hybrid Yeah, very likely.

Answer (score 6):

### Try something like:

(As supposed at: [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield))

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import urllib2
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='read', blank=True)
    creative_url = models.URLField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"

    def download_image(self, url):
        input_file = StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
        output_file = StringIO()
        img = Image.open(input_file)
        if img.mode != "RGB":
            img = img.convert("RGB")
        img.save(output_file, "JPEG")
        self.image.save(self.name+".jpg", ContentFile(output_file.getvalue()), save=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.download_image(self.creative_url)
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

solution using **requests**

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from requests import request, HTTPError

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        data = request('GET', self.creative_url,)
        data.raise_for_status()
        self.image.save('fname.jpg', ContentFile(data.content),save=False)
    except HTTPError:
        pass
    super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```