# Programmatically add file to Django ImageField

Tags: python, django, urllib2

I'm trying to download an image file from a URL and then assign that image to a Django ImageField. I've followed the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield?lq=1) and [here](

My model, in pertinent part, looks like this:

```
class Entity(models.Model):

     logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=_getLogoPath,null=True)
```

The _getLogoPath callback is pretty simple:

```
def _getLogoPath(self,filename):
    path = "logos/" + self.full_name
    return path
```

The code for fetching and saving the image file is also straightforward as part of a custom django-admin command that I plan on running as a regularly scheduled cron job:

```
...
img_url = "http://path.to.file/img.jpg"
img = urllib2.urlopen(img)
entity.logo.save(img_filename,img,True)
...
```

When I run this, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute 'chunks'
```

I also tried adding `read()` to the image but resulted in a similar error. I also tried writing the image to a temporary file and then trying to upload that, but I get the same error.

Comment: Can you add the part of the code which throws the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you [read the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField) you will see that the second argument to `entity.logo.save` needs to be an instance of `django.core.files.File`

So to retrieve an image and then save it using the imagefield you would need to do the following.

```
from django.core.files import File

response = urllib2.urlopen("http://path.to.file/img.jpg")
with open('tmp_img', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(response.read())

with open('tmp_img', 'r') as f:
    image_file = File(f) 
    entity.logo.save(img_filename, img_file, True)
os.remove('tmp_img')
```

The object you receive back from the call to `urlopen` is not the image itself. It's `read` method will return the binary image data though.

Comment: You can use `from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile` instead of `tmp_img`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url/2141823#2141823).