# Use facebook picture as default picture. Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-facebook

I'm using django-facebook and I would like the profile-picture to be the picture of my user when they register with facebook.

In my custom User model (Userprofile) I have a

```
         profilpic = models.ImageField(...)
```

I also have this function in my models.py:

```
   def create_facebook_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if not created:
          return
      UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

   post_save.connect(create_facebook_profile, sender=User)
```

I was wondering if it's possible to use the facebook profile picture as the 'profilpic' of my user.

I tried to do that:

```
     def create_facebook_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if not created:
          return
      UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

      user_data = json.loads(instance.raw_data)          
      user_pic = user_data.get('image')
      user = request.user
      user.userprofile.profilpic = user_pic
      user.save()

   post_save.connect(create_facebook_profile, sender=User)
```

But it doesn't work. Any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save the URL to an `ImageField`, you need to actually read and save the image from Facebook locally first and then assign that new file to the `ImageField` (assuming that the json actually has an image url). Have a look at this similar question:

[Django: add image in an ImageField from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url)