# django upload file using JSON

Tags: json, django, file, save

i have JSON request like this:

`object: { "fields":{ "src" : "http://dss.com/a.jpg", "data" : " //file is here" } }`

i have the model like this:

`class FileMy(models.Model):
    f = models.FileField(upload_to='file_path/',)`

How to save the file ?

Comment: i don't think that is the proper way, you need a form on the client side that posts the file to the django view which can then save the file in the file system.  you probably don't want to store a blob image in your database but just a reference to where the file can be found on your file system.  This link may help in regards to an upload form posting an image to a django view via ajax.   https://waaave.com/tutorial/django/how-to-quickly-upload-files-in-ajax-with-django-in-5-steps/

Comment: thanks, i split JSON and file data

Answer (score 0):

You may use urllib to read the file and then you can add it to your model.

Take a look at this post:
[Django: add image in an ImageField from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url)

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to wrap the data in a [ContentFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class) which inherits from File and then [save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) the file to the model directly.

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

from .models import FileMy

f1 = ContentFile("esta sentencia está en español")
f2 = ContentFile(b"these are bytes")
m1 = FileMy()
m2 = FileMy()
m1.f.save("filename", f1, save=True)
m2.f.save("filename", f2, save=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, encode the raw data in the json request body.

```
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from django.core.files import File

def save_file_to_field(field, file_name, raw_content):
    # field: reference to the model object instance field
    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(raw_content)
    field.save(
        file_name,
        File(img_temp)
    )
    img_temp.flush()
```

What does this do:

- creates a temporary file on your system that holds the data
- uses the file field save method to trigger the usual file handling
- deletes the temporary file