# uploading file and title using query parameters

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views, django-rest-framework

I am using Django RestFramework. I would like to if it is possible to upload a file and title using url parameter. For example,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/title='some-title'&file_url='some-path'
```

Can anyone please guide as i am beginner in django rest framework.Here is my code:

**Model:**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='No title', unique=True)
    file_url = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ('created_at',)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file_url = serializers.FileField(max_length=None, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'file_url', 'created_at')
```

**Views:**

```
class MyViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

class MyAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

def get_queryset(self):

    title = self.lookup_field['title']
    file_path = self.lookup_field['file']
    obj = MyModel.objects.create(title=title, file_url=file_path)
    serializer = MySerializer(obj)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**Urls:**

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'django', MyViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
url(r'^upload/(>P<title>[\w+])&?P(<file>[\w+])/$', MyAPIView.as_view()),
url(r'^', include(router.urls))
]
```

**I want to get the result like:**

[image]

Comment: There are fixes for what you're trying to achieve but if you're planning to go to production, this will be very inefficient. Django may not be the best option to serve static/media files. You can use django-storages to store the file on aws s3!

Comment: @MananMehta so it means we cannot create/post data through url?

Comment: You can but will be inefficient for a production server!

Comment: If you're persistent on doing what you're doing, I can go home and post some code to do this (in a couple hours). I think you'll have to first use native python code to download the file from the url and then pass it to the django file field! Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url and see if it helps

Comment: Thanks. i would appreciate!

Comment: In the meanwhile, you can also look at the ProfilePictureUpload class at https://github.com/mehtamanan/MoviebookAPI/blob/master/userprofiles/views.py. It takes a file object, not a URL but it might help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send data through url like this, use query params instead of modifying your url regex like this.

Your url will simply be

```
url(r'^upload/$', MyAPIView.as_view())
```

on frontend you will append `title` and `path` in the url like this

```
localhost:8000/api/v1/upload?title=<your_title>&path=<your_file_path>
```

and then in your views you can simply extract these key value pairs from `request.query_params`

But I would advise not to use this for `POST` methods, where you can send all this data in `request.data`.