# Is there a way to stream data directly from python request to minio bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, stream, python-requests, minio

I am trying to make a GET request to a server to retrieve a tiff image. I then want to stream it directly to MinIO using the put_object method in the MinIO python SDK.

I know I could do this by saving the image to a temp file, then uploading but I wanted to see if I could skip that step.

I've tried inserting the byte response directly and using BytesIO to wrap it but I think I am missing something.

```py
r = requests.get(url_to_download, stream=True)
Minio_client.put_object("bucket_name", "stream_test.tiff", r.content, r.headers['Content-length'])
```

I get back the following error

> AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi @JudsonCrouch if my answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Reading [documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/python-client-api-reference.html#put_object) on MinIO about `put_object`, there are examples how to add a new object to the object storage server. Those examples only explain how to add a file.

This is definition of `put_object` function:

`put_object(bucket_name, object_name, data, length, content_type='application/octet-stream', metadata=None, progress=None, part_size=510241024)`

We are interested in `data` parameter. It states:

> Any python object implementing io.RawIOBase.

[RawIOBase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase) is base class for raw binary I/O. It also defines method `read`.

If we were to use [dir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) built-in function to attempt to return a list of valid attributes for `r.content`, we could then check if `read` is there:

`'read' in dir(r.content)` -> return `False`

That's the reason why you get `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'read'`. It's because `type(r.content)` is `bytes` class.

---

You can convert `r.content` into class that inherits from `RawIOBase`. That is, using `io.BytesIO` class. To get size of an object in bytes, we could use `io.BytesIO(r.content).getbuffer().nbytes`.

So if you want to stream raw bytes of data to your bucket, convert `bytes` class to `io.BytesIO` class:

```
import io
import requests

r = requests.get(url_to_download, stream=True)
raw_img = io.BytesIO(r.content)
raw_img_size = raw_img.getbuffer().nbytes

Minio_client.put_object("bucket_name", "stream_test.tiff", raw_img, raw_img_size)
```

---

*NOTE*: Examples show reading binary data from file and getting its size by reading `st_size` attribute from `stat_result` which is returned by using `os.stat()` function.

`st_size` is equivalent of to `io.BytesIO(r.content).getbuffer().nbytes`.

Comment: What do you mean by `url_to_download`? What should be added there? Something like e.g. `localhost:5000/streamToMinio`? I tried your solution because I have to deal with a similar problem but I get an `InvalidSchema` exception

Comment: OP has asked how to stream tiff image directly into MinIO without downloading it first . `url_to_download` would be endpoint where this tiff image is located at.

Answer (score 2):

You can stream your file directly into a minio bucket like this:

```py
import requests

from pathlib import Path
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

client = default_storage.client
object_name = Path(urlparse(response.url).path).name
bucket_name = settings.MINIO_STORAGE_MEDIA_BUCKET_NAME

with requests.get(url_to_download, stream=True) as r:
    content_length = int(r.headers["Content-Length"])
    result = client.put_object(bucket_name, object_name, r.raw, content_length)
```

Or you can use a django file field directly:

```py
with requests.get(url_to_download, stream=True) as r:
    # patch the stream to make django-minio-storage belief
    # it's about to read from a legit file
    r.raw.seek = lambda x: 0
    r.raw.size = int(r.headers["Content-Length"])
    model = MyModel()
    model.file.save(object_name, r.raw, save=True)
```

The RawIOBase hint from Dinko Pehar was really helpful, thanks a lot. But you have to use response.raw not response.content which would download your file immediately and be really inconvenient when trying to store a large video for example.