# Uploading images from a CSV file to Django model instances while using bulk_create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a project built with Django Rest Framework. In one of the views, I'm implementing a functionality that takes a CSV file sent from the frontend (React.js), and that creates model instances from the rows of the CSV file.

This is the model that I'm trying to upload:

```py
class ModelExample(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    logo = models.ImageField(...)
    .
    .
    .
```

This is the code that I'm using to create the model instances:

```py
class ModelExampleCreateAPIView(APIView):
    
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        .
        .
        .
        modelExampleList = list()
        reader = pd.read_csv(file)
        for rowIndex, row in reader.iterrows():
            newModelExample = ModelExample(
                                           name=row['Name'],
                                           # logo = row['Logo']
                                          )
        modelExampleList.append(newModelExample)
        ModelExample.objects.bulk_create(modelExampleList)
        .
        .
        .
```

This is an example of the CSV file that I'm using:

| Name | Logo |
| --- | --- |
| Name Example 1 | https://url-to-logo-1 |
| Name Example 2 | https://url-to-logo-2 |

My question is how can I assign the logo column to the model instances. The solutions I have found so far force to save the model instances inside of the loop (in the view) instead of using bulk_create. Since I'm creating a considerable amount of model instances at once, I need to use the bulk_create instead of saving one by one.

All suggestions are very appreciated

**These are some of the links I have found:**

- [Programmatically saving image to Django ImageField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308386/programmatically-saving-image-to-django-imagefield)
- [Django: add image in an ImageField from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url)

**Note:** I do not want to save the url but the image from the url itself.